# Ajustar div rotado dentro de otro div

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid-layout

Estoy contruyendo un monopoly con grid. Cuando cuando roto los divs por separado, algunos quedan completamente bien encajados dentro del elemento que tiene la clase grid, pero algunos no se acaban de ajustar muy bien.
 No tengo muy claro si es por temas de renderización del navegador o es que algo estoy haciendo mal. Abajo he adjuntado el código html, css y una imagen que explica claramente lo que comento que me sucede.

Aquí está el código:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap:2em;
}

.element {
    border:2px solid black;
    height: 159px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.largeElement {
    grid-column: 2/5;
    grid-row: 2/5;
    border: none !important;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size: 100px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    padding-top: 200px;
}

.element p {
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    margin:0;
}

.topPart {
    height: 50px;
}

.box05, .box07, .box08 {
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.box02, .box03, .box04 {
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.box01 {
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.box01, .box09 p {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
}

.box09 {
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box01">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box02">
                    <div class="topPart green"></div>
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box03">
                    <div class="topPart green"></div>
                    <p>3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box04">
                    <div class="topPart green"></div>
                    <p>4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box05">
                    <div class="topPart blue"></div>
                    <p>16</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="largeElement">
                <div class="box06">
                    MONOPOLY
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box07">
                    <div class="topPart blue"></div>
                    <p>15</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box08">
                    <div class="topPart blue"></div>
                    <p>14</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box09">
                    <p>9</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box10">
                    <div class="topPart red"></div>
                    <p>12</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box11">
                    <div class="topPart red"></div>
                    <p>11</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="element">
                <div class="box12">
                    <div class="topPart red"></div>
                    <p>10</p>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Adjunto una imagen para enseñar exactamente el problema que tengo ya que no acabo de entender a que se debe el problema:

[image: Problema al ajustar los divs dentro de un grid]

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Te falta añadirle el width a la clase `element`, por lo que veo son cuadrados... Despues de este cambio no logro simular tu problema ni con chrome ni con firefox. `.element {
    border:2px solid black;
    height: 159px;
    width: 159px;
}`

Comment: Ahora se ve perfecto. Muchas gracias x3k_js. Solucionado!

Comment: He creado una respuesta, para que quede la pregunta como cerrada por favor aceptala. Me alegro que este solucionado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que quede cerrada la pregunta:

Faltaba el `width` en la clase `element`. Ya que son elementos cuadrados y tienen un `height` estático el `width` debería de ser el mismo.

```
.element { 
    border:2px solid black; 
    height: 159px; 
    width: 159px; 
}
```